# Highcharts - per customer- even small date/range increments must be visible

Tags: jquery, charts, highcharts

I have an issue where small date/ranges are not visible on GANTT charts with long timelines. This example [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2xkfm87e/17/) has two date ranges (Category 2 and Category 7)  that are only a few days long. However, the timeline is about 5 years long. The customer does not want to have to zoom in to see this. I could pad the dates, but then the tool-tip would display incorrect dates and this  could affect decision making. I've spent days trying to work this one out so any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

```
    $(function () {
    /**
     * Highcharts X-range series plugin
     */
    (function (H) {
        var defaultPlotOptions = H.getOptions().plotOptions,
            columnType = H.seriesTypes.column,
            each = H.each;

        defaultPlotOptions.xrange = H.merge(defaultPlotOptions.column, {});
        H.seriesTypes.xrange = H.extendClass(columnType, {
            type: 'xrange',
            parallelArrays: ['x', 'x2', 'y'],
            animate: H.seriesTypes.line.prototype.animate,

            /**
             * Borrow the column series metrics, but with swapped axes. This gives free access
             * to features like groupPadding, grouping, pointWidth etc.
             */  
            getColumnMetrics: function () {
                var metrics,
                    chart = this.chart,
                    swapAxes = function () {
                        each(chart.series, function (s) {
                            var xAxis = s.xAxis;
                            s.xAxis = s.yAxis;
                            s.yAxis = xAxis;
                        });
                    };

                swapAxes();

                this.yAxis.closestPointRange = 1;
                metrics = columnType.prototype.getColumnMetrics.call(this);

                swapAxes();

                return metrics;
            },
            translate: function () {
                columnType.prototype.translate.apply(this, arguments);
                var series = this,
                    xAxis = series.xAxis,
                    yAxis = series.yAxis,
                    metrics = series.columnMetrics;

                H.each(series.points, function (point) {
                    barWidth = xAxis.translate(H.pick(point.x2, point.x + (point.len || 0))) - point.plotX;
                    point.shapeArgs = {
                        x: point.plotX,
                        y: point.plotY + metrics.offset,
                        width: barWidth,
                        height: metrics.width
                    };
                    point.tooltipPos[0] += barWidth / 2;
                    point.tooltipPos[1] -= metrics.width / 2;
                });
            }
        });

        /**
         * Max x2 should be considered in xAxis extremes
         */
        H.wrap(H.Axis.prototype, 'getSeriesExtremes', function (proceed) {
            var axis = this,
                dataMax = Number.MIN_VALUE;

            proceed.call(this);
            if (this.isXAxis) {
                each(this.series, function (series) {
                    each(series.x2Data || [], function (val) {
                        if (val > dataMax) {
                            dataMax = val;
                        }
                    });
                });
                if (dataMax > Number.MIN_VALUE) {
                    axis.dataMax = dataMax;
                }
            }                
        });
    }(Highcharts)); 


var series= [{
   data: [  { 
            name: 'Criteria 1',
            x: Date.UTC(2010,5,19),
            x2: Date.UTC(2015,5,22),
            y:8,        
            tooltip_data:'',
            color:'#000000'     
        } , { 
            name: 'Criteria 2',
            x: Date.UTC(2015,5,19),
            x2: Date.UTC(2015,5,22),
            y:7,        
            tooltip_data:'',
            color:'#000000'     
        } , { 
            name: 'Criteria 3',
            x: Date.UTC(2011,0,19),
            x2: Date.UTC(2015,5,22),
            y:6,        
            tooltip_data:'',
            color:'#000000'     
        } , { 
            name: 'Criteria 4',
            x: Date.UTC(2013,6,19),
            x2: Date.UTC(2015,5,22),
            y:5,        
            tooltip_data:'',
            color:'#000000'     
        } , { 
            name: 'Criteria 5',
            x: Date.UTC(2010,9,19),
            x2: Date.UTC(2015,5,22),
            y:4,        
            tooltip_data:'',
            color:'#000000'     
        } , { 
            name: 'Criteria 6',
            x: Date.UTC(2014,10,19),
            x2: Date.UTC(2015,5,22),
            y:3,        
            tooltip_data:'',
            color:'#000000'     
        } , { 
            name: 'Criteria 7',
            x: Date.UTC(2011,2,19),
            x2: Date.UTC(2014,3,19),
            y:2,        
            tooltip_data:'Not meeting criteria.',
            color:'#ff0000'     
        } , { 
            name: 'Criteria 7',
            x: Date.UTC(2015,5,19),
            x2: Date.UTC(2015,5,22),
            y:2,        
            tooltip_data:'',
            color:'#000000'     
        } , { 
            name: 'Criteria 8',
            x: Date.UTC(2010,5,19),
            x2: Date.UTC(2015,5,22),
            y:1,        
            tooltip_data:'',
            color:'#000000'     
        } , { 
            name: 'Criteria 9',
            x: Date.UTC(2010,5,19),
            x2: Date.UTC(2015,5,22),
            y:0,        
            tooltip_data:'',
            color:'#000000'     
        }] }]


    // THE CHART
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'xrange'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Category History',
                style: {
                    color: '#525151',
                    font: '20px Helvetica',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
        },

        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats:{
                month: '%b - %Y'
            }, 
            labels: {
                style: {
                    color: '#525151',
                    font: '12px Helvetica',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
            },              
            startOnTick: true,
            tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
            tickInterval: 3 * 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000,
            endOnTick: true,
            minPadding: 0,
            maxPadding: 0,
            gridLineWidth: 1
        },
        yAxis: {
            min:0,
            useHTML: true,
            categories: ['Category 9',
                         'Category 8',
                         'Category 7',
                         'Category 6',
                         'Category 5',
                         'Category 4',
                         'Category 3',
                         'Category 2',
                         'Category 1'],
            tickInterval: 1,            
            tickPixelInterval: 200,
            labels: {
                style: {
                    color: '#525151',
                    font: '12px Helvetica',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
            },
            startOnTick: false,
            endOnTick: false,
            title: {
                text: 'Criteria',
                style: {
                    color: '#525151',
                    font: '15px Helvetica',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
            },
            minPadding: 0.2,
            maxPadding: 0.2
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.point.options.name + '</b><br/>' + this.point.options.tooltip_data + '<br>' +
                    Highcharts.dateFormat('%m-%d-%Y', this.point.options.x)  +
                    ' - ' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%m-%d-%Y', this.point.options.x2 )+ '<br>'; 
            }
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                borderRadius: 5,
                pointWidth: 10,
                colorByPoint: true
            }
        },
        series: series


    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how would this work. In short I would edit source in the jsFiddle for the gantt chart.

It's like this:

```
                H.each(series.points, function (point) {
                    barWidth = xAxis.translate(H.pick(point.x2, point.x + (point.len || 0))) - point.plotX;

                    // added min bar width:
                    if(barWidth < minWidth) {
                        barWidth = minWidth;
                    }
                ...
```

Ande [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2xkfm87e/18/).

Now just play around with that `barWidth` option. Additionally you may want to edit `point.plotX` option.

==========

Another solution is to use different x-dates, as you suggested. Than in tooltip display proper one, for example point may look like this:

```
{
  x: Date.UTC(..),
  x2: Date.UTC(..),
  y: value,
  realStart: Date.UTC(...),
  realEnd: Date.UTC(...),
}
```

Where `realStart` is well, real starting date of the bar. Now in `tooltip.formatter`, you have access to this values: `this.point.options.realStart`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I haven't had time to test it yet but I'll report back when I do.

Comment: Thank you for getting back with me. This is a big help. I like option two best because (as the demo in first option demonstrates) if the point occurs at the end of the timeline, it sticks out past the point where the other lines stop. In this instance my business rules state the chart ends as of the date viewed and this could be confusing for the customer. 

Two excellent options, Thank You!!

Comment: Well.. for me it always be confusing ;) You can change width of the bar, but either it will **start** or **end** with improper date. First demo shows that End point is wrong. Instead you can also edit `point.plotX` value, but, well, since second option works for you, that's great!

Comment: Thankfully, Highcharts added this feature: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.xrange.minPointLength